# How does https check md5, sha-1 and sha-2 fingerprints?

Tags: tls, hash, web-browser, http, internet

When a https site shows multiple finger prints, i.e.: md5 and sha1, or sha256 and sha1, how does the browser check?
is it both just the "strongest" or whatever is convenient?

This question arose because somewhere it was stated that a site used weak protection because of sha1. 
But that site also showed a sha256 fingerprint.

Is it possible that because of also having sha1 that that counts as the weakest link for spoofing, man-in-the-middle etc.?
(or in other cases md5 as weakest link).

Comment: Read the section on `Basic TLS Handshake` in this link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 1):

The browser checks both fingerprints. The idea behind that is if it is possible to create a fake certificate with the same `MD5` or `SHA-1` hash, there is a much lower (almost zero) probability the same certificate second hash also matches. This could be called: Dual Hash Fingerprinting. Both `MD5` and `SHA-1` are considered vulnerable in theory (`MD5` also in practice). This is one reason to move to `SHA-1/SHA-256`. Even if a collision is possible for `SHA-1`, it is almost impossible to get the same collision for `SHA-256`.

A note here, is that longer fingerprints may be truncated and `SHA-256` has longer fingerprint than `SHA-1` and the same with `SHA-1` and `MD5`.